# Rolling window calculation is added to the dataframe as a column of NaN

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame that is indexed from 1 to 100000 and I want to calculate the slope for every 12 steps. Is there any rolling window for that?

I did the following, but it is not working. The `'slope'` column is created, but all of the values as `NaN`.

```
!pip install yfinance
import yfinance as yf 
from scipy.stats import linregress
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# test data
df = yf.download('^GSPC',start='2009-11-26',end='2014-12-31',interval='1d')

# I want to get the slope for the Close every 7 days 
def get_slope(array):
    y = np.array(array)
    x = np.arange(len(y))
    slope, intercept, r_value, p_value, std_err = linregress(x,y)
    return slope


# calculate slope of regression of last 7 days
days_back = 7

df['slope'] = df.groupby(df.index)['Close'].rolling(window=days_back,
                               min_periods=days_back).apply(get_slope, raw=True).reset_index(0, drop=True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. It's not necessary to use `.groupby` because there is only 1 record per day.
2. Don't use `.reset_index(0, drop=True)` because this is dropping the date index. When you drop the index from the calculation, it no longer matches the index of `df`, so the data is added as `NaN`.

   - `df['Close'].rolling(window=days_back, min_periods=days_back).apply(get_slope, raw=True)` creates a `pandas.Series`. When assigning a `pandas.Series` to a `pandas.DataFrame` as a new column, the indices must match.

```py
# add the slope column
df['slope'] = df['Close'].rolling(window=days_back, min_periods=days_back).apply(get_slope, raw=True)

# plot slope
df.plot(y='slope')
```

[image]